# Need advice - how can we improve process of uploading photos and videos that verify user's profile?

Tags: forms, uploading, upload

I really need your advice - we have a dating feature on site, where people can verify their profiles uploading photos or videos with their usernames and name of site. The problem is that 80-90% of people upload anything except what they have to upload on a verification page. Is it same on other dating sites?

Any ideas, what's wrong with upload page?

Here is a screenshot of uploading page:
[image: Screenshot of a page]

Answer (score 4):

Your sample guy doesn't look like he enjoys following instructions...

Don't use a random sample, use a dedicated picture with annotations (e.g use a generally bright photo, and circle the important elements in red, and label them):

- You
- xhamster.com
- your username

Use a few smaller ones to show common mistakes, e.g. like that:
[image]

---

Rationale: People don't follow instructions, especially when they are... on the hunt. Use less words, more pictures. Positive feedback through a friendly sample image, with clearly labeled requirements. Negative feedback for unwanted behavior. In combination, the user can "guess" an acceptable amount of readability, etc.

---

I think seeing a random sample image at that point has some benefit - e.g. making the page more personal. You might even rotate / regulary change the sample picture, and use pictures from existign users that agreed. (Idea: "Award" this status to paying members)

---

You might try some server side OCR and face recognition. It would be an interesting project for sure, but I doubt it's easy to setup or maintain against breaking attempts. However, immediate automatic rejection would drive home the point that you take this verification serious.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful. We'd work on it:)

Comment: +1 good answer! you can also actually just use face detection, to make sure there's **a** face in the photo.